# Replace some string in a file and save it

Tags: perl

I want to replace some string in a file and save it back.
I have already code which can open the file, find the string and replace it. But file is not getting saved. What is wrong with it?

```
open MYINPUTFILE, $EventLog;
my @lines = <MYINPUTFILE>; # read file into
my @errors = ();
my $size = $#lines + 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    if ($lines[$i] =~ m/$s1(.*)$s2/) {
        $lines[$i] =~ s/$s1(.*)$s2/$s1.($1+4).$s2/eg;
        print $lines[$i] ;
    }
}
close MYINPUTFILE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script opened the file in read mode, and printed to STDOUT. 
You need to open a second temporary file, write the changed output to it. And finally, remove the first file and rename the temporary file as your final file.

Also, I'd do this:

Replace FILEHANDLES:

```
open my $input_file, '<', $EventLog or die $!;
```

Don't read the whole file into a array (it's a bad idea for huge files). Read line by line and handle it properly:

```
while( my $line = <$input_file> ) {
   #...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's good advice about this subject in the Perl FAQ.

[How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.16.1/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)